# Firebase database trigger - how to wait for calls

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am having trouble making asynchronous operations in firebase database functions.

I have tried the code below

```
exports.onTodoCreate = functions
.region('europe-west1')
.database
.ref('/todos/{userId}/{todoId}')
.onCreate( async (snapshot, context) => {
  console.log('Begin')
  //Collect email address
  const email = 'test@somewhere.com'

  let otherUser = {}
  let otherUserExists = false
  await snapshot.ref.root.child('users')
  .orderByChild('email')
  .equalTo(email)
  .on('value', (userSnapshot) => {
    userSnapshot.forEach((data) => {
      //Collect data
      otherUser = {
        ...data.val()
      }
      otherUser .id = data.key
      otherUserExists = true
      console.log('otherUserExists-1', otherUserExists)
    })
  })
  console.log('otherUserExists-2', otherUserExists)
```

The expected output is:

```
Begin
otherUserExists-1 true
otherUserExists-2 true
```

What I see in the logs is:

```
Begin
otherUserExists-2 false
otherUserExists-1 true
```

How can I make Google Cloud Functions (Firebase database trigger) to wait for the database call to finish before proceeding? I have several calls that needs to be executed asynchronously and wish not to have to nest them to force asynchronous operation.

Comment: Instead of `.on()` try using `.once()` which returns a promise.

Comment: If you are getting started with Cloud Functions and Realtime Database, you might want to start with some video tutorials.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[on()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Query#on) attaches a persistent listener to a query that will get invoked with the data at that location, and again for each change to any data at that location.  The method does not return a promise.  This is almost certainly never what you want to do in Cloud Functions.

Instead, if you need to get data a single time, use [once()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Query#once), which returns a promise that resolves with a snapshot of the requested data.

Comment: Thank you very much! Of course! How could I miss that? :D

Comment: You are a life saver! @doug This also solved my problems with the wrong triggers being invoked! (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57465045/firebase-database-trigger-oncreate-gets-triggered-on-delete-and-update) Many thanks!